# What is the meaning of updoots?

Tags: word-meaning

Today I encountered the word **updoots** in [this SO meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321059/2947415)

> I think it is correct.
>
> Technically if you have a post with 2 or more **updoots** on a meta it did
>   at some point have exactly two.
>
> The rules do not say that the posts with exactly 2 have to happen at
>   the same time, just that you have to have had them.

and I was thinking if it's just a typo meaning uproot, but then I realized that it doesn't make sense. Then I saw the comment below saying

> **+1 for saying updoots**. – Don't Panic 1 hour ago

Then [I search on the internet](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=updoots%20meaning) regarding the meaning of it and all I saw is **just a bunch skeleton**

It even have a result [like this](http://www.vocabularie.com/updoot)

> Updoot Misspelling
>
> What is the meaning of misspelled word updoot?
>   1. Did you mean uproot? - The meaning of uproot

Comment: I think that just **upvotes**  misspelled.

Answer (score 8):

It's something of an internet meme. There's a [picture](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/skull-trumpet) that's popular of a skeleton playing a trumpet. Because trumpets (in a very vague sense) make something of a 'doot' noise, people started referring to the meme by using variations on 'doot'. Some of these are 'updoot' (a variation of 'upvote') or 'doot doot mr. skeltal'.

Comment: Also see http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/skull-trumpet

Comment: See also the green updoot on his skull: [Skull With Updoot](http://imgur.com/gallery/WWlBxF6)